# I want to get the number of Instagram followers of a user with just id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, instagram

Well I want to create a form where if user add their Instagram id can get the absolute number of followers without "k" abbreviation. But I don't have any idea how to do it. If you know please help me. It would be appreciated if you could post the code...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you haven't even started, how does this question relate to Wordpress or JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be able to take care of the form creation and handling part. If not, please read some beginner level tutorials to get some ideas.

Regarding the followers count, you can do a GET request to this url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1
```

Replace `<username>` with the user's instagram username. This will return JSON data.
And you can access the followers count from `graphql -> user -> edge_followed_by` in that JSON object.

Here's a sample URL: https://www.instagram.com/akhileshbc/?__a=1

And it's JSON data:

```
{
    "logging_page_id": "profilePage_532689420",
    "show_suggested_profiles": false,
    "show_follow_dialog": false,
    "graphql": {
        "user": {
            "biography": "Simple, humble and quiet. \ud83e\udd37\u200d\u2642\ufe0f\n- Chaliyan \ud83e\udd2a\n- Loves driving \ud83d\ude97\n- Loves coding \ud83d\udcbb\nSookshich nokkendeda unnii.. Ithu njaan alla! \ud83d\ude01",
            "blocked_by_viewer": false,
            "restricted_by_viewer": null,
            "country_block": false,
            "external_url": "http://www.akhileshbc.com/",
            "external_url_linkshimmed": "https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.akhileshbc.com%2F&e=ATPlLqbGaXUR5wlxwYIjsDftFcWyvLfqAzAc3d6HlzF0-U3YZQF6veDJXH6zg8P1AZ8ZM-eaE0zJGZ18&s=1",
            "edge_followed_by": {
                "count": 516
            },
            "fbid": "17841400522608323",
            "followed_by_viewer": false,
            "edge_follow": {
                "count": 195
            },
            "follows_viewer": false,
            "full_name": "Akhilesh B Chandran",
            "has_ar_effects": false,
            "has_clips": false,
            "has_guides": false,
            "has_channel": false,
            "has_blocked_viewer": false,
            "highlight_reel_count": 0,
            "has_requested_viewer": false,
            "id": "532689420",
            "is_business_account": false,
            "is_joined_recently": false,
            "business_category_name": null,
            "overall_category_name": null,
            "category_enum": null,
            "category_name": null,
            "is_private": true,
            "is_verified": false,
            "edge_mutual_followed_by": {
                "count": 0,
                "edges": []
            },
            "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.ftrv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/53646757_406084366897615_5102538752442499072_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ftrv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=hRS4KKbebn4AX-ZnN7t&tp=1&oh=8e2899b2638452829998bf7e6e451df1&oe=601F3EB5",
            "profile_pic_url_hd": "https://instagram.ftrv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/53646757_406084366897615_5102538752442499072_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ftrv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=hRS4KKbebn4AX-ZnN7t&tp=1&oh=a12a5d28edda0906ed2e318e75d47392&oe=6020E3C5",
            "requested_by_viewer": false,
            "should_show_category": false,
            "username": "akhileshbc",
            "connected_fb_page": null,
            "edge_felix_video_timeline": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
            },
            "edge_owner_to_timeline_media": {
                "count": 47,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
            },
            "edge_saved_media": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
            },
            "edge_media_collections": {
                "count": 0,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": []
            },
            "edge_related_profiles": {
                "edges": []
            }
        }
    },
    "toast_content_on_load": null,
    "show_view_shop": false,
    "profile_pic_edit_sync_props": null
}
```

Here's **516** is the count of my followers.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess the only way is to get the HTML page of that user and search for that info.
I suggest to create an API in the cloud, so that you can change the mechanism quickly as the HTML of the site changes.

Regards